# Aggregate & insert collection into a different collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I am trying to merge data from a collection named `reviews` into another collection named `products`. I want to merge all `reviews` for a given `product`, into the **product** in the `products` collection as an array named **reviews**.

For example, here is a product object followed by a review object:

A specific product -

[image: A specific product]

A few reviews for the above product -

[image: A few reviews for the above product]

I have attempted to aggregate the data using the below code but I don't know how to insert them into the `products` collection.

```
db.getCollection('reviews').aggregate( [
                  { $match: {db_asin: "3866811659"}},
                  { $group: {_id: null, reviews : { $push:  "$$ROOT" }}},
                  { $out : "products.db_asin.3866811659" }
              ] )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the aggregation to product collection and use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to pull reviews from another collection on db_asin.

Something like

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {"$match": {"db_asin": "3866811659"}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"reviews",
    "localField":"db_asin",
    "foreignField":"db_asin",
    "as":"reviews"
  }}
]).forEach(function(doc){ 
  var _id = doc._id; 
  var reviews = doc.reviews; 
  db.products.update({"_id" : _id},{"$set": {"reviews" : reviews}})
});
```

Edit: Added closing bracket at the end of forEach loop

Comment: Hi Veeram, appreciate the answer. By doing this, the products collection under that specific product now does have a reviews array, however its all mongo stats.

Comment: This is what is in the reviews array: "reviews" : [ 
        {
            "_mongo" : {
                "slaveOk" : true,
                "host" : "localhost:27017",
                "defaultDB" : "test",
                "_readMode" : "commands",
                "_writeMode" : "commands"
            },
            "_db" : {
                "_mongo" : {
                    "slaveOk" : true,
                    "host" : "localhost:27017",
                    etc.......

Comment: Np. How/where are you running this query ? Can you try running the query from mongo shell ?

Comment: I was originally running it in Robo 3T, I tried running it in the Shell to now joy. Weirdly enough now the code isn't even producing a reviews array.

Comment: Ah Veeram I can see this has actually worked. It has created a new collection called, products.db_asin. 3866811659, is there anyway that rather than create a new collection, it merges into the old product collection?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thats perfect than you Veeram, just edited it to add a missing closing bracket on the For loop.